# "Have a breakfast" or "eat a breakfast" in AmE

Tags: word-choice, verbs, american-english

Which expression do Americans prefer, *have a breakfast* or *eat a breakfast*?

Comment: A side note; Having breakfast is, in my opinion, more technically correct as it can contain both eating and drinking whereas eating breakfast would, again technically speaking, omit the act of drinking.

Comment: The preceding comment is a great example of why it should be possible to downvote comments.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Usually, we omit the *a* in a situation like this:

> I'm going to eat/have breakfast.

Unless you want to say something like this:

> I usually eat a [adjective] breakfast.

Or:

> We're having a breakfast meeting.

Etc.

But in the specific case you asked about, *eat* and *have* are interchangeable. They both convey the same message.

According to this Ngram, *have* is more common, but just barely.
[image]

Note: I'm not actually American, but seeing as how there isn't much variation between American and Canadian English, I would say I can still answer this question. I also used the American English corpus for my Ngram.

Comment: +1 Great comment.  You nailed it.  Not much variation between American and Canadian English, eh?  Apparently so.

Comment: It would be nice if you'd included a link to the NGram itself, so I could check British usage (where [as I expected](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+breakfast%2Ceat+breakfast&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3), we significantly prefer **have breakfast**). Not surprising in my case, since I can hardly **eat** a cigarette and cup of coffee!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Click on the image, it will take you there.

Comment: @Mahnax: Gosh! I don't know if I've ever seen that style before! I even called up "edit" on the answer to see how you did it, but it looks waaay too hard for me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's just HTML, heh.

Comment: I learnt how to do NGrams a few weeks after coming here about a year ago, and I learnt how to do footnotes today. Maybe I'll learn how to do "hotspot" charts next year - a man can only take in so much at once!

Comment: @FumbleFingers links: <a href=[address here, in quotes]>text or image</a>.

Comment: I'll favourite this question so I can come back and crib from that when I'm feeling gung-ho! (just not tonight, Josephine! :)